# Getting error while trying to create not updatable view in Oracle

Tags: oracle, view

I have two tables iot_test1 & iot_test2 with below contents.

```
FULL_NAME
Chanchal
Bappa
Bappa

SUBJECT---
Oracle
Unix
Unix
```

I am getting below error while trying to create the below non-updatable view.

```
CREATE VIEW vw_ChanchalTest AS 
SELECT full_name, subject FROM iot_test1, iot_test1;
```

> Error: Error starting at line : 1 in command - CREATE VIEW
>   vw_ChanchalTest AS  SELECT full_name, subject FROM iot_test1,
>   iot_test1 Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00904: "SUBJECT": invalid
>   identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

I am pretty new to this.
Please suggest.

Comment: Check if you use double quotes to create the fieldnames like `"Full_Name"` on that case oracle fieldname will be case sensitive

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, that is not the case here. This is pretty annoying me. Please help.

Comment: You're joining `iot_test1` to itself (and doing an implicit Cartesian product which seems wrong).  If I follow your description `iot_test2` is the table that has a `subject` column.  If `iot_test1` does not have a `subject`, you'd get this error.

Answer (score 0):

You suppose to use in the from part `iot_test1, iot_test2` , but your query is using the same table twice `iot_test1, iot_test1` and in one of them `subject` column do not exists .

Comment: This should work for you CREATE VIEW vw_ChanchalTest AS 
SELECT full_name, subject FROM iot_test1, iot_test2;

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped.